# How to get JqueryUI to work with ASP.Net Master Pages and multiple paths?

Tags: jquery-ui, master-pages

I have a simple ASP.Net 4.0 website that uses a master page that I would like to include JqueryUI.
The Head looks like this.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $("#accordion").accordion();
         });
</script>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Everything works fine for content pages that inherit from the Master Page as long as it is in the same directory. So if the content page is /Home.aspx alls good, but if it is /Sales/Home.aspx the the styles are never applied to the accordion that is desfined n the Master Page.

Comment: ~ doesn't mean anything to the browser. It's only useful in a server.mappath statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using ... "js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/ .. you're redirecting to the JS folder, relativily (is that a word?) to the folder of the current page. If that's in Sales/..., it's looking for the JS-folder in Sales/ but it probably isn't there. You can prevent this by using an absolute link to the root:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This way it will look for the JS folder in the root of the site.