# How do I resolve paths of images in css style sheet while using master pages

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am having a problem with image paths in my css. My directory structure is below with folders in bold.

mp.master has a reference in it for menu.css, both of my testpages are using mp as its master page. testpage2.aspx (in the root folder) looks correct, testpage1.aspx (inside of a sub folder) is not able to find images (ie navBG.png) specified in menu.css. If I move testpage1.aspx to the root it works fine.

Other styling in menu.css is applied to testpage1.aspx, just not images.

**WebSiteFolder**

- **css**
  - menu.css
- **img**
  - navBG.png
- **SubDirectory**
  - testpage1.aspx
- mp.master
- testpage2.aspx

In menu.css I have the following:

```
 .no-cssgradients nav, .no-js nav { padding-bottom:4px; border:none; background:url(../img/navBG.png) repeat-x 0 0; }
```

What am I doing here? I have tried to state the absolute path with ~/,  ./,  ../ but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The code you have should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here [How to get JqueryUI to work with ASP.Net Master Pages and multiple paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417641/how-to-get-jqueryui-to-work-with-asp-net-master-pages-and-multiple-paths). I was making a site to try out some css3/jquery stuff and my problem was not in referencing my css, but in referencing the jquery library.

this.Page.ResolveURL is your friend here:
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= this.Page.ResolveUrl("~/resources/js/jQuery.js")%>'>

Comment: Thanks a million. After hours of trying and search, this is the best solution and the very .NET way.... !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try `/img/navBG.png`. Basically this means that you are using an absolute path in css. Caution: absolute path in css means that the image uri is in the following pattern `[host name] + [url you have specified in css]`, so if your site is located in virtual folder the uri won't be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `/img/navBG.png`?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use absolute pathing rather than relative.  /img/navBG.png is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the CSS file from Solution Explorer to the head section of the master page in code view :)

Your CSS rule and path are correct.